# How do I set the video processor mode on the EVR filter?

Tags: c++, graph, filter, directshow

I am using the `EVR` filter in graph and I need to set the video processor mode to `DXVA2_VIDEOPROCPROGRESSIVEDEVICE` to avoid an interlacing problem. I can do this manually in GraphEdit, but cannot figure how to do it programatically.

`IMFVideoProcessor::SetVideoProcessorMode` seems an obvious choice so I've obtained a pointer to `IMFVideoProcessor`, but I'm struggling to know what to pass to it. `DXVA2_VIDEOPROCPROGRESSIVEDEVICE` is defined as a GUID in `dxva2api.h` and casting it to an LPGUID gives the link error below.

some code snipits:

```
IMFVideoProcessor* m_pProcessorCtrl;
hr = pGS->GetService(MR_VIDEO_MIXER_SERVICE, IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_pProcessorCtrl));
m_pProcessorCtrl->SetVideoProcessorMode((LPGUID)&DXVA2_VideoProcProgressiveDevice);
```

obviously there's a bit more to it than that, but hopefully you get the idea.

The linker error:

`error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _DXVA2_VideoProcProgressiveDevice`

Does anyone know how I set the video mode?

I'm using C++ with MFC, VS2008, developing on Vista, targeting Vista and above.

Comment: A reply elsewhere suggested that I should #include <initguid.h> before the #include <dxva2api.h> to resolve the linker error. Unfortunately this had no effect.

Comment: With help from the Media Foundation forum, I got it compiling with the following changes:

in the header:
extern "C" const GUID __declspec(selectany) DXVA2_VideoProcProgressiveDevice =
{0x5a54a0c9, 0xc7ec, 0x4bd9, {0x8e, 0xde, 0xf3, 0xc7, 0x5d, 0xc4, 0x39, 0x3b}};

in the code:
GUID guid = DXVA2_VideoProcProgressiveDevice;
m_pProcessorCtrl->SetVideoProcessorMode(&guid);

Unfortunately, this is not fixing the interlacing issue and when the graph is viewed in graph edit, the video processor mode is not set. Back to the drawing board I guess.